# classify website business domain

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, classification

I want to identify the Category/business_domain of the website's business to which it belongs.

For ex. superhuman website. The company made Email client powered by buzzword features & UI.

So in short Category of website can be **Professional Email services**.

So, to get this done, some of my initials thoughts are applying [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) algorithm (python module) on About_us text of a website & company's Facebook info page, given that we have these both. But still this approach is not working in many cases. Any insights?

LDA details:
using 20000 passes and 1 topic, my results for http://aakritiartgallery.com/ website is

```
[(0, u'0.050*art + 0.020*aakriti + 0.019*contemporary + 0.017*gallery + 0.015*new')]
```

How can i narrow down to my business with these term probablities given by LDA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anony-Mousse said it well, it would help to make a roadplan instead of fixating on a single algorithm. Given your situation, this is what I would do.

## Preprocessing/Feature Extraction

NMF, LSA, LDA are unsupervised techniques mostly used in preprocessing to extract meaning features. In NLP, this usually corresponds to extracting meaningful words in large amounts of text. By using these techniques, you would be able to process raw data to gain meaningful features. These algorithms by themselves do not offer predictions, and they are usually not enough to create a good model.

## Training

In your case, you would need structured data to train your model and make predictions. For instance, you can use your results of your LDA (you would actually use indices of these keywords) mapped to a business domain (or your label).

i.e)
(label)IT : (features) java, python, server
(label)Zoo: (features) monkey, zebra, giraffe
(label)IT : (features) nlp, machine learning

After you have gathered some data (at the very least (#features * #label)), you can train a supervised model of your choice. (Log Reg, SVM, NN, etc.)

## Testing

Evaluate your prediction score and implement algorithm.

Having said this, this would be no easy task. You would have to deal with identifying categories/subcategories, other means of extracting meaningful features, etc so I would put a long timeframe on this project. Good Luck!

Comment: that's pretty much okay, but will i be able to even classify if let's say there are two companies, one which only given information about medicines, the other which also sells them, so to distinguish between them is tough since both would have exactly same features

Comment: You can think of LDA as a 'keyword generator' to be crude, so I would use it to predict a general field of a company. If you want to differentiate between 'medicine information' and 'medicine distribution', you would first need features other than keywords--i.e number of links, most frequently used words, etc. For practical use, it would be good not to exceed 1000 features--otherwise you would start to need to worry about speed/memory performance.

Comment: Try to gather as most information as you can, and use feature reduction techniques if necessary. Also, you would need to create separate 'labels'  ('medicine information', 'medicine distribution', 'medicine production'... ) before generating the data.

Comment: In my opinion, what you are trying to accomplish is definitely possible with a high F-score, but I would start with a small subset of business types (like focusing only on medicine related businesses) and expand your model afterwards. Hopefully this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get training data
2. Train a classifier
3. Classify!